# EF Core can't translate an expression to compare two collections which EF 6 could

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following query in the old Entity Framework (.NET Framework):

```
db.ProductVariations
    .Where(pv => pv.Product.Categories
        .Any(cat => categorySearchStrings
            .Any(categorySearchString => cat.SearchTree.StartsWith(categorySearchString))));
```

*I realize this isn't pretty, but I'm refactoring a legacy app and we have to choose our battles.*

So what happens is that you can pass a list of search string (the `categorySearchStrings`), e.g.:

```
"38.54.", "45."
```

This is basically an implementation of a [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) where each category in our database has a `SearchTree` property. So a category with search tree `38.54.99` would match, but `38.` would not.

A product can have multiple categories and we can pass in multiple search tree strings to the query. So we're comparing two collections.

This gets translated to

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[ProductVariation] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent3].[SearchTree] AS [SearchTree]
                FROM  [dbo].[ProductCategory] AS [Extent2]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CategoryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                WHERE [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[ProductId]
            )  AS [Project1]
            WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX(N'38.', [Project1].[SearchTree]) AS int)) = 1
            )
        )
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

I'm trying to migrate to Entity Framework Core (6, running on .NET 6) but this now gives me the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'categorySearchString => categorySearchString == "" || EntityShaperExpression: 
        Company.Data.Models.Category
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
        IsNullable: False
    .SearchTree != null && categorySearchString != null && EntityShaperExpression: 
        Company.Data.Models.Category
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
        IsNullable: False
    .SearchTree.StartsWith(categorySearchString)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Switching to client evaluation isn't really an option I believe, because there's too many data that will be retrieved. Plus, there's more going on than just this Where clause. I simplified it.

I also tried rewriting it as this:

```
.Where(pv => pv.Product.Categories.Select(c => c.SearchTree).Any(st => categorySearchStrings.Any(ss => st.StartsWith(ss))));
```

But I just get the same error.

Is it possible to do this with EF Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to build a dynamic [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) to represent the filter:

```c#
var cat = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Category), "cat");
var parts = new List<Expression>(categorySearchStrings.Count);
var startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.StartsWith), new[] { typeof(string) });

foreach (string categorySearchString in categorySearchStrings)
{
    var searchTree = Expression.Property(cat, nameof(Category.SearchTree));
    var value = Expression.Constant(categorySearchString);
    var startsWith = Expression.Call(searchTree, startsWithMethod, value);
    parts.Add(startsWith);
}

var body = parts.Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
var categoryFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Category, bool>>(body, cat);

var pv = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductVariation), "pv");
var product = Expression.Property(pv, nameof(ProductVariation.Product));
var categories = Expression.Property(product, nameof(Product.Categories));
var any = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new[] { typeof(Category) }, categories, categoryFilter);
var finalFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductVariation, bool>>(any, pv);

db.ProductVariations
    .Where(finalFilter)
    ...
```

You should also report this as [an issue on the efcore repository](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues), to see if it can be fixed in a future version.

Update: the issue was [created](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27205) but was a duplicate of an [existing issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19070).

Comment: I can't seem to pass in the filter. It compiles when I pass in filter.Compile(), but then I get an error: `System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Func<Company.Data.Models.Category,System.Boolean>' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Company.Data.Models.Category,System.Boolean>>' of method 'Boolean Any<Category>(System.Linq.IQueryable<Company.Data.Models.Category>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Company.Data.Models.Category,System.Boolean>>)' (Parameter 'arg1')`

Comment: Looks like you called `.Compile()` on the `Expression<Func<Category, bool>>`, which turns it into a `Func<Category, bool>` that can't be used with Entity Framework.

Comment: But the project won't compile if I just pass in `filter` like in your answer. VS tells me: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Company.Data.Models.Category, bool>>' to 'System.Func<Company.Data.Models.Category, bool>'`

Comment: Looks like you need to build the filter from a higher level. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Had to make a slight change to get it working (see edit), but other than that it works now. Thanks. I will file a bug as you proposed.